# Windows keyboard won't type capitalized T

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard

I'm trying to simply type capitalized T on my 64b Windows 7.
What happens is this. Everything works fine. Keyboard types letters, small or capitalized until I get to letter T. Only here it doesn't work.

I have Windows 7 Ultimate and keyboard is connected via USB.

This isn't program related, but rather system wide bug.

Has anyone had some problem like this.

Comment: What happens if you press shift+T? Nothing? Lower-case t?

Comment: Run `osk.exe`, see if it shows `T` in there when you're typing.

Comment: It's a strange keyboard malfunction. When i hold down left shift, capital T won't work. If I hold down right shift, capital P won't work but capital T works. Tried another keyboard, and it is not system related, but keyboard bug

Comment: @VukBG - If another keyboard works.  The simplest explaination is that the keyboard is defective.

Comment: I'm using a USB Magic Switch which allow my mouse & keyboard to work for 2 different computers.  Interestingly enough on 1 of the computers the s key work fine for lower/upper cases, but for the other computer neither the lower case s nor the caps lock upper case s works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a hardware failure. The keyboard is connected internally in a matrix layout. This means that connections are shared between multiple keys to reduce the total number of connections needed to the control chip. Normally this is not a problem, but on some keyboards, the keyboard can't register all the keys if you press 3 or more keys. This is because some combinations could be caused by multiple different key combinations, and the keyboard can't be sure of which combination you pressed.

See for example the keyboard matrix pad below, which would sit under the keys. The three parts are sandwiched together. There are two plastic sheets with conductive traces, and an isolating plate with holes in between. When a button presses down from above, two points on the plastic sheets make contact through the holes in the isolating plate.

[image: Keyboard pads]

If you would for example Q and S, and then press A or W, the keyboard controller can't be sure which of them you pressed, because the same electrical lines are all short circuited.

The exact matrix layout is different between keyboard models, and I would guess that there's some hardware fault that makes two points short out when you press T or P, triggering the same kind of error condition where the keyboard controller can't be sure what is being pressed. This could have various causes like liquid stuck between the contact pads, or a misalignment. I would suggest getting a new keyboard, and if you're curious, taking apart this keyboard to see how it looks inside.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well. Someone suggested one of their F-Keys was tilted. I swept my fingers across all my F-keys several times and my problem input: Shift-V immediately started working again. FIXED.

Comment: Solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

In my case the uppercase-a would not appear when typing it. After an hour of unsuccessful problem-searching (plugging the keyboard into different USB-ports, uninstalling and reinstalling the keyboard drivers, going into the PC's UEFI to check the legacy USB setting, case-reading on the internet) I suddenly realized the cause: Some hours before, I had installed a screen capture program and in there I had stupidly assigned Shift-A to be the video capture hotkey. So that was taking priority of that key combination.
I could have realized earlier that the problem was related to the screen capture program because when testing if an uppercase-a could be typed into the password box of the Windows login screen, this went without a problem. But once in Win 10, no uppercase-a possible. Well, the reason for that was that during installation of the screen capture program I had configured it to start when Windows starts. Long story short: See if there's a program on the PC taking priority of the troubled key(s).

Comment: This is very helpful for me. Your post saved me hours of unnecessary troubleshooting effort. Indeed, some random software may thin it is a good idea to define `Shift + P` or `Shift + Q` as proper shortcuts. I guess these are people who only use CapsLock to type capital letters?

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your keyboard (unless top is sealed), especially under your problem keys, T, P, and Shift.  I always do the control, alt, win, menu, space, enter, and usually home keys as well.

While the keyboard may be failing or originally faulty, my experience with several keyboards (including the one I'm using right now) is that dirt/grime/skin oil and flakes/sesame seeds/eyelashes/... collect under the keys.

I start with a quick pass with a toothpick between all the keys to loosen the dirt then quickly vacuum the keyboard.  I use a cannister floor vac with a scrap of screen or panty hose over the end (or just your fingers) or a small portable kitchen pickup vac.  Filter: I've never had a key pop loose but I know someone who did.  Then I try to gently raise the individual problem keys (T, P, and Shift in this case) and poke around with the toothpick, dragging loose material away from the center of each key.  Vacuum again if this exposes more loose material.

If necessary, removed the problem key tops.  **CHECK** keyboard model online for cleaning hints/problems **FIRST**, but most key tops pop off.  **BE CAREFUL** because some key tops are attached with small plastic tabs that break easily if manipulated the wrong way or with excessive force.

Edit: As nitro2k01 notes, the keyboard may be broken but his diagram reminds me that sometimes the problem ( e.g., sesame seed in top layer hole in his diagram) can be under a completely different key than the one that appears to be failing because of the way the paths in these layers/membranes overlay each other.

Edit: Three more cleaning hints:

- Alcohol on a cotton swab sometimes helps (but remove loose cotton threads and twirl/tighten cotton first to reduce fragments that catch).
- Compressed air in a can sometimes helps.  I've also moved the hose to the outlet on the vaccuum (start with a NEW BAG!).
- Pressing the adjacent key down while gently lifting the adjacent edge of the problem key may provide access without removing the key tops.

Answer (score 0):

I am in the same boat with Windows 10 and Shift p.  The only way I can get a capital p is with all caps on and hitting p.  Not with shift p.  I replaced keyboard with a USB keyboard and another time with a wireless keyboard and got same results, which tell me it is not hardware related.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's system bug. Before login windows(7 64bit), I can input A by shift+a. After logon, I can't input by shift+a anymore. But it can be input by CAP.
I am using laptop with logitech wireless mouse+keyboard. The problem found on both built-in and external keyboard.

Comment: Are you guessing with the word "think" or do you have a definitive answer? Read over https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead when you get a chance and once you get here you can write comments.